# Angular checkbox click and $resource leads to SecurityException: The operation is insecure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm

I'm tring to combine angular.js with calls to Microsoft Dynamics CRM webapi endpoint.

The webpage displays list of items as checkboxes. Ticking an unticked checkbox should perform an association. Unticking a ticked checkbox shoud perform a disassociation.

You will see in the code below that association does work but disassociation does not. I cannot set a plunker because the code is tied to Microsoft Dynamics CRM application.

First, the HTML part

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="../../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="crmwebapimodule.js"></script>
    <script src="manyrelationshipapp.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="crmApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppController" class="col-sm-7 col-md-2">
        <div ng-repeat="match in matches">
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{match.recordId}}" ng-model="match.checked" ng-click="doAction(match.recordId, match.checked)" />
            <span for="{{match.recordId}}">{{match.label}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then my CRM module

```
// create a module with a dependency on ngResource
var angularMscrm = angular.module('ManyRelationshipAngularMscrm', ['ngResource']);

// define the CrmService factory
angularMscrm.factory('CrmWebApiService', function ($resource) {
    var oDataUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + '/api/data/v8.1/';

    var defaultParams = {};

    // describe our API actions
    var actions = {
        GetActiveItems: {
            isArray: false,
            method: 'GET',
            url: oDataUrl + ':entitySet?$select=:primaryField',//&$filter=statecode eq 0',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
                'OData-Version': '4.0'
            }
        },
        GetSelectedItems: {
            isArray: false,
            method: 'GET',
            url: oDataUrl + ':entitySet(:primaryEntityId)?$select=:primaryField&$expand=:entityRelationName($select=:secondaryPrimaryField)',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
                'OData-Version': '4.0'
            }
        },
        Associate: {
            method: 'POST',
            url: oDataUrl + ':primaryEntitySet(:entityId)/:entityRelationName/$ref',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
                'OData-Version': '4.0'
            }
        },
        Disassociate: {
            method: 'DELETE ',
            url: oDataUrl + ':primaryEntitySet(:primaryEntityId)/:entityRelationName(:secondaryEntityId)/$ref',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
                'OData-Version': '4.0'
            }
        }
    };

    // create the service
    return $resource(oDataUrl, defaultParams, actions);
});
```

Finally, the controler itself

```
/// <reference path="CrmWebApiModule.js" />
(function () {
    // create a module for our Angular app with a dependency on our angularMscrm module
    var CrmApp = angular.module('crmApp', ['ManyRelationshipAngularMscrm']);

    // create a controller for the page, and inject our CrmService into it
    CrmApp.controller('AppController', function ($scope, CrmWebApiService) {
        // Data for test purpose
        var params =
        {
            recordId: '{32A33A4B-99A4-E511-80C0-00155D0A061D}',
            primaryEntitySet: 'opportunities',
            primaryIdAttr: 'opportunityid',
            primaryField: 'name',
            secondaryEntitySet: 'competitors',
            secondaryIdAttr: 'competitorid',
            secondaryPrimaryField: 'name',
            entityRelationSet: 'opportunitycompetitors_association'
        };

        if (params.recordId.length == 38) {
            params.recordId = params.recordId.substr(1, 36);
        }

        $scope.matches = new Array();

        $scope.doAction = function (id, value) {
            if (value === true) { 
                CrmWebApiService.Associate({
                    primaryEntitySet: params.primaryEntitySet,
                    entityId: params.recordId,
                    entityRelationName: params.entityRelationSet
                },
                {
                    "@odata.id": Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + '/API/data/v8.1/' + params.secondaryEntitySet + '('+ id +')'
                }, function(response) {
                     alert(httpResponse);
                });
            } else {
                CrmWebApiService.Disassociate({
                    primaryEntitySet: params.primaryEntitySet,
                    primaryEntityId: params.recordId,
                    entityRelationName: params.entityRelationSet,
                    secondaryEntityId: id
                }, function (response) {

                },
                function(httpResponse) {
                    alert(httpResponse);
                });
            }

        }

        CrmWebApiService.GetActiveItems({
            entitySet: params.secondaryEntitySet,
            primaryField: params.secondaryPrimaryField
        },
            function (response) {
                var data = response.value;

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $scope.matches.push({
                        recordId: data[i][params.secondaryIdAttr].toLowerCase(),
                        label: data[i][params.secondaryPrimaryField],
                        checked: false
                    });
                }
            });

        CrmWebApiService.GetSelectedItems({
            entitySet: params.primaryEntitySet,
            primaryEntityId: params.recordId,
            primaryField: params.primaryField,
            entityRelationName: params.entityRelationSet,
            secondaryPrimaryField: params.secondaryPrimaryField
        },
            function (response) {
                var data = response[params.entityRelationSet];

                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.matches.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                        if ($scope.matches[i].recordId === data[j][params.secondaryIdAttr]) {
                            $scope.matches[i].checked = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    });
}());
```

Soo, the association works as expected but the disassociation leads to the following error:

```
Error: The operation is insecure.
hf/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular.min.js:84:6
s@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular.min.js:80:22
m/f<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular.min.js:77:308
f/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular.min.js:107:349
Ge/this.$get</k.prototype.$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular.min.js:121:189
Ge/this.$get</k.prototype.$digest@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular.min.js:118:296
Ge/this.$get</k.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular.min.js:121:458
tc[c]</<.compile/</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular.min.js:220:167
$e/c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.4/angular.min.js:32:253
e/<()angular.min.js (ligne 99)
ye/this.$get</<(a=Object { type="object"}, c=undefined)angular.min.js (ligne 74)
f/<()angular.min.js (ligne 107)
Ge/this.$get</k.prototype.$eval(a=Object { type="object"}, b=undefined)angular.min.js (ligne 121)
Ge/this.$get</k.prototype.$digest()angular.min.js (ligne 118)
Ge/this.$get</k.prototype.$apply(a=Object { type="object"})angular.min.js (ligne 121)
tc[c]</<.compile/</<(d=Object { type="object"})angular.min.js (ligne 220)
$e/c(c=Object { type="object"}, e=undefined)angular.min.js (ligne 32)
```

I just don't get what is insecure and how to resolve this problem...

The only difference I see is that association works with HTTP POST and disassociation with HTTP DELETE but it does not lead me to a resolution.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hey Tanguy, welcome to SO, that's a lot of code, is it all strictly required for this question? Do you think it would be possible to edit it to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example; http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. This will make it easier for us to answer.

Comment: did you try to get replicate the HTTP DELETE request generated by your code using Postman? Also maybe it's a typo but there is a space after the word delete ('DELETE ')

Comment: @JamesWood as I'm a newbie in Angular, I was thinking that I may have done some silly mistake. That's why I posted all the code

Comment: Ok, I'm so sorry but @GuidoPreite found the solution... it was just this damn extra space I did not notice

Comment: @TanguyTouzard glad you solved :)